# Apache Virtual host not working

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) to set up Apache virtual host, but browser is unable to serve the homepage.

Here is my .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ednet.dev
    ServerName ednet.dev
    ServerAlias www.ednet.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ednet/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my host file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   asad-HP-ProBook-4530s
127.0.0.1   ednet.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

but when i try to open `ednet.dev` in browser it gives error

```
This site can’t be reached
ednet.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

`sudo netstat -na | grep 80` Output

```
asad@asad-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ sudo netstat -na | grep 80
tcp        0      0 10.99.2.62:41650        104.244.43.80:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.99.2.62:38314        216.58.208.83:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 10.99.2.62:38808        216.58.198.2:443        ESTABLISHED
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    147808   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28097    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28080    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32880    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28098    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28680    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28074    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27800    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-HdPg5eVU
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28062    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     48980    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19180    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28081    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25580    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28073    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     39680    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28099    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     129780   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28059    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    24180    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28066    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28061    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     58380    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28060    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28096    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     40808    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28065    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28056    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20780    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22801    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27804    @/tmp/dbus-EvBU16isPp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27806    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-HdPg5eVU
```

`sudo lsof -i -n -P +c 0 | grep ':80\|:443'` output:

```
asad@asad-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ sudo lsof -i -n -P +c 0 | grep ':80\|:443'
[sudo] password for asad: 
chrome       3333       asad  166u  IPv4 169400      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:52109->216.58.208.78:443 
chrome       3333       asad  178u  IPv4 169585      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:50478->151.101.193.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  198u  IPv4 162437      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:57394->151.101.113.147:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  225u  IPv4 171167      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:39238->104.16.108.18:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  253u  IPv4 171168      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:39240->104.16.108.18:443 (CLOSE_WAIT)
chrome       3333       asad  260u  IPv4 171157      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:50480->151.101.193.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  262u  IPv4 168483      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:59052->216.58.208.66:443 
chrome       3333       asad  263u  IPv4 169398      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:47762->216.58.208.68:443 
chrome       3333       asad  270u  IPv4 170224      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:41851->216.58.208.78:443 
chrome       3333       asad  271u  IPv4 168485      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:35004->23.58.0.61:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  272u  IPv4 169426      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:56116->192.0.73.2:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  287u  IPv4 161862      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:38618->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  288u  IPv4 131203      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:37862->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  300u  IPv4 171145      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:38814->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  305u  IPv4 170154      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:39516->23.57.249.169:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  308u  IPv4 168478      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:35000->23.58.0.61:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  311u  IPv4 129805      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:37858->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  313u  IPv4 128964      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:37854->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  324u  IPv4  85748      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:48908->151.101.65.69:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  335u  IPv4 131349      0t0  TCP 10.99.2.62:37868->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome       3333       asad  337u  IPv4 169446      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:33691->216.58.210.66:443 
chrome       3333       asad  341u  IPv4 169448      0t0  UDP 10.99.2.62:38019->216.58.210.66:443 
apache2      3679       root    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2      3682   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2      3683   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2      3684   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2      3685   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2      3686   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Please, provide the output of `sudo netstat -na | grep 80`.

Comment: Better, use `sudo lsof -i -n -P +c 0 | grep ':80\|:443'` to find which service is using HTTP|HTTPS ports 80|443.

Comment: Does browsing to **http://localhost/** show the default page of a web server?

Comment: Yes, localhost show default page

Comment: is your apache configured to use your document root to search for its files?

for instance could it serving from your `htdocs` directory? (this was the case on my windows machine)

Comment: First don't forget to restart or reload Apache after change of its configuration. Second try to use different domain extension, for example `.org` instead `.dev`. Recently I found that, Chromium/Chrome (sometimes) has strange behaviour when the domain extension is `.dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but after uninstalling whole LAMP stack and reinstalling it again solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

At first, be sure that your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` contain line `Listen 80`

At second, be sure that you have enabled your config using `sudo a2ensite yoursite.name`.

At third, be sure that you have disabled default virtualhost `sudo a2dissite 000-default`

Also add options for your documentroot directory, for example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ednet/public/ >
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

Then, restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart` and try to get access to virtualhost using the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
apache2      3686   www-data    4u  IPv6 153144      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Apache obviously only listens on IPv6 for some reason.

Change `/etc/hosts` to IPv6:

```
127.0.0.1   ednet.dev
```

to

```
::1   ednet.dev
```

This will enable you to use IPv6 for reaching the name.

Answer (score 0):

You apache is obviously listening to IPv6, to test it you can do:

```
 wget http://[::1]/ -O /dev/null
```

and you will get `200 Ok` as response

to make apache listen to only IPv4 addresses you add:

```
 Listen 0.0.0.0:80
 Listen 192.0.2.1:80
```

source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html#ipv6

Comment: $wget http://[::1] / -O /dev/null  
    --2018-02-28 11:34:16--  http://[::1]/  
    Connecting to [::1]:80... connected.  
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden  
    2018-02-28 11:34:16 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
    /: Scheme missing.

Comment: Also when i try to access `ednet.dev` chrome redirects it to `https://ednet.dev` , could `https` might be problem?

Comment: @AsadHayat well, if you have a redirection in you html page you must enable https by mystifying `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` and then `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`. Also you can check the permissions on your `/var/www/html/endnet` and change it to www-data by typing `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/ednet`